# SSL Error Twitter Request using HTTPS

Tags: ruby, https, twitter

**consumer** and **token hash** is defined in my code

```
access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.from_hash(consumer, token_hash)
url = URI.encode("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=awesome!")
response = access_token.request(:post, url)
```

it gives us

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:586:in `connect'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:586:in `connect'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:553:in `do_start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:542:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1035:in `__request__'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/net_http_ext.rb:51:in `request'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/oauth-0.4.7/lib/oauth/consumer.rb:161:in `request'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/oauth-0.4.7/lib/oauth/tokens/consumer_token.rb:25:in `request'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/oauth-0.4.7/lib/oauth/tokens/access_token.rb:12:in `request'
```

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Use Latest RVM (Ruby Version Manager) to fix third party app integration by using Ruby on Rail framework.

For more info use Step by Step guide here - [OpenSSL Errors and Rails Certificate Verify Failed](http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html)

Hope it helps!

Comment: You dont need RVM to install the certificates, but this is a better approach than turning off all verification

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I still havn't been able able to resolve the underlying issues but try pasting this into your .rb files.

```
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

It basically turns off the verification step.

Comment: where exactly would this go? Im using the oauth gem with cucumber and not sure how to implement this

Comment: **The line must go before you call the third party servers.**                       require 'rubygems'
require 'twitter'
require 'mongo'
require 'date'
require 'time'

time = Time.new
print "start_timestamp: #{time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")}\n"
#print "\nInit Security Disable\n"
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE 

print "\nConnect to Mongo\n"